# How to copy weights of selected vertices to different vertex group

Tags: vertex-groups, vertex-weights

The title should be self-explanatory - I need to select some vertices and copy&paste their weights to different vertex group (within the same object).
Other vertices weights must stay untouched.
I guess I need some fancy addon for this simple task?

Comment: How are the vertex-groups related: location? topology? Are they in the same / separate objects?

Comment: Within the same object, I need to copy the weights of the selected vertices to the same vertices, just in a different vertex group.